# Track changes / revisions script in PHP?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a form that submits data into a database. If the table is populated with content, it will display the content in the textarea for the form with the appropriate data from the table.

I want to make it so that when someone submits a revision to what was already written, you can track that change and separate it from the old stuff (like highlighting) similar to Wikipedia's history function.

Does anyone know how I could do this in PHP?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

There is an implementation of [diff in pure PHP](http://www.holomind.de/phpnet/diff.src.php) which you could use to save different revisions.  So, save the first input and then keep saving the diffs

Comment: I actually found this: https://github.com/chrisboulton/php-diff to be more like what I need. Thanks for putting me on the write track for searching.

Comment: Glad to know you got what you were looking for :)

Comment: Anyone know how to install this in CakePHP?