# How can I keep track of changes to content? - i.e. revision history

Tags: asp.net-mvc-2, c#-4.0, .net-4.0

I searched and found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4929165/track-changes-revisions-script-in-php). But that question and the solution deal with PHP.

I am developing many applications in ASP.Net MVC 2. Each one has some type of text content that users can post. Example: Website, Blog, Issue Tracking, Comments.

I want to maintain the revision history of each one and show the changes made from one revision to another, when requested. You know.. the deleted content is shown in red with a strike-through and the added content is shown in green etc.. that type of thing.

I am not sure whether you save the changes alone for each revision, or save the whole content and calculate the diff when showing or how it is done.

Is there a .Net library that lets me do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You may find the [following component](http://www.mathertel.de/Diff/Default.aspx) useful.

Comment: It worked perfectly. In fact it is so accurate and exact that it made me laugh - diff these two sentences and you'll know what I mean: *"Take three bananas, 1 cup of milk, quarter cup of sugar and blend them."* and *"Take two bananas, 1 and half cup of milk, 4 table-spoons of sugar and blend them."* :) Semantically, the diff is hilarious. To the common user, "three" was replaced by "two". But according to the program, "hree" was replaced by "wo".. haha :)